# ASP.NET Core MVC - starts to query database, then stops with no errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple project, and I am a little new. All I am trying to do is with a brand new project list the users and roles in the system. I have already created my `ApplicationUser` model and logins using the scaffolding.

Now I am trying create a controller with a model and view. However it seems to start to query the database, then just stops with no information... Has anyone seen this? Can you point me in the right direction possibly?

I seem to have gotten stuck and do not have enough experience to figure this one out.

Controller

```
public class UserRolesController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    //private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public UserRolesController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager/*, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager*/)
    {
        //_roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Administration()
    {
        var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();

        var userRolesViewModel = new List<UserRolesViewModel>();

        foreach (ApplicationUser user in users)
        {
            var thisViewModel = new UserRolesViewModel();
            thisViewModel.UserId = user.Id;
            thisViewModel.FullName = user.FullName;
            thisViewModel.Email = user.Email;
            //thisViewModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            //thisViewModel.LastName = user.LastName;
            //thisViewModel.Roles = await GetUserRoles(user);

            userRolesViewModel.Add(thisViewModel);
        }

        return View(userRolesViewModel);
    }
}
```

Debug log:

> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.1\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled. The thread 0x6e4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> {"EventId": 20101, "LogLevel": "Information", "Category": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", "Message":"Executed DbCommand (49ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType=\u0027Text\u0027, CommandTimeout=\u002730\u0027]\r\nSELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[BirthDate], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[FullName], [a].[JobDescription], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName]\r\nFROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]","State":{"Message":"Executed DbCommand (49ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType=\u0027Text\u0027, CommandTimeout=\u002730\u0027]\r\nSELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[BirthDate], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[FullName], [a].[JobDescription], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName]\r\nFROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]", "elapsed":"49", "parameters":"", "commandType":"Text", "commandTimeout":30, "newLine":"
> "commandText":"SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[BirthDate], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[FullName], [a].[JobDescription], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName] FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]","{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType=\u0027{commandType}\u0027, CommandTimeout=\u0027{commandTimeout}\u0027]{newLine}{commandText}"}}   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (49ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[BirthDate], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[FullName], [a].[JobDescription], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName] FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
> The thread 0x6cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: "then just stops with no information" - what does that mean? No data is returned from the database? The application freezes? An exception is thrown?

Comment: Are there any users in your database?

Comment: Can you capsulate your code with try/catch and get what is the actual err?

Comment: I will try the encapsulate. Yes there are users and no the application does not freeze or throw an exception. Just stops processing the page. I can still use the other portions of the site.

Comment: Can you use the debugger and put a break on say the foreach loop to see what's happening?  You could then roll over the "users" variable and see if it is populated and then step through the foreach loop to see if it is doing any work.

Comment: Yeah that’s my next step is to figure out logging on statements.

Comment: What is the code for this UserManager class?

Comment: Ensure you have no calls to Wait, Result, or GetAwaiter in your application. If you don't, then reduce the code to a minimal reproducible example and update the question with code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You can run generated sql query in DataBase, and check if can get expected result or some error occurs.